# Cannot uninstall osxfuse from Homebrew

Tags: homebrew, macfuse

I have an old Macbook Pro where I apparently installed osxfuse at some point. Now I can't uninstall it, even though it's listed as installed.

I tried updating the OS to macOS Monterey 12.1, and I'm running the latest version of Homebrew. `brew doctor` shows no issues, just "Your system is ready to brew."

Any ideas?

Here is the problem:

```
➜  ~ brew list
==> Formulae
adns        ca-certificates gmp     libassuan   libidn2     libunistring    ncurses     openssl@3   pinentry-mac    unbound
autoconf    direnv      gnupg       libevent    libksba     libusb      nettle      p11-kit     pkg-config  watch
bdw-gc      gdbm        gnutls      libffi      libnghttp2  libuv       node        pcre        readline    xz
brotli      gettext     guile       libgcrypt   libtasn1    libyaml     npth        pcre2       sphinx-doc  zsh
c-ares      git     icu4c       libgpg-error    libtool     m4      openssl@1.1 pinentry    sqlite      zsh-completions

==> Casks
osxfuse. <--!!

➜  ~ brew uninstall osxfuse --cask
Error: Cask 'osxfuse' is not installed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the directory where casks are stored with `cd $(brew --prefix)/Caskroom`.
Remove the cask manually with `rm -rf osxfuse`.
Confirm that it's gone with `brew list`.
In my case, osxfuse seems to have been made obsolete along the way and imperfectly removed (probably by brew) with some leftover cask metadata in the Caskroom directory. To be sure, use `kextstat | grep osxfuse` to see if the kernel extension is still there and if so you'll need to do some more cleanup.

Comment: Somehow, between me asking the question and you answering it, it seems that osxfuse is no longer an installed cask. Marking as right answer anyway.